# Illegal offset type (Internal server error) on Auth::guard(config('sanctum.guard', 'web'))

Tags: php, laravel, graphql

I have been following the instruction on Lighthouse:

https://lighthouse-php.com/5/security/authentication.html

Then, when I implemented the stateful authentication example, I encountered **Illegal offset type (Internal server error)** on this line:

```php
$guard = Auth::guard(config('sanctum.guard', 'web'));
```

As my research, I found out that `Auth::guard()` expects `string` as parameter, but `config()` returns `mixed|\Illuminate\Config\Repository`. So, that is why it looks like returning **Illegal offset type**.

When I changed the line to the following, the error disappeared, and it seems to be working:

```php
$guard = Auth::guard('web');
```

Is this a right way to fix it?

What do I need to do to make the example work correctly?

---

### Environment:

- laravel: 9.11
- laravel/sanctum: 2.14.1
- lighthouse: 5.50
- laravel-graphql-playground: 2.6

Answer (score 0):

As you see, if you look at the default [sanctum config](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/blob/863b610662bc09091fb73188f127d65eb64d3398/config/sanctum.php#L36). The key `sanctum.guard` is an array, so you are passing an array, to an method that expects a string.

I'm not certain it is the right approach going forward, but for here and know fix of your current problem. Unpack the array instead.

```
Auth::guard(Arr::first(config('sanctum.guard', ['web'])));
```

Comment: I would like to suggest Lighthouse to update their document since the current code does not work. I will wait for another few days, and if I do not see any other answers, I will suggest your answer to them. It could end up with finding out I was simply doing something wrong, though....

Comment: In the link you have sent i can not see your example thou

Comment: Oh..., if you got to this link: https://lighthouse-php.com/5/security/authentication.html#stateful-authentication-example

Then, see the implementation of __invoke() method of Login and Logout classes. There is a line as `$guard = ?;`. Above that line, it says `Plain Laravel: Auth::guard()` and `Laravel Sanctum: Auth::guard(config('sanctum.guard', 'web'))`. I am using `sanctum` so that I changed the line to `$guard = Auth::guard(config('sanctum.guard', 'web'));`.

That may be what I am doing wrong...? 